# How do I disable the game component "TilemapCollider2D" from events with my sprite?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I need to make my sprite go through the tilemap but I can't get the "TilemapCollider2D" component to do that.

I tried to set up the declaration and disabling code from this URL: `https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html`
I thought it would be simple and disable collison but nonetheless I'm told that "You probably need to add a TilemapCollider2D to the game object "Diver". Or your script needs to check if the component is attached before using it."